# Use WCF Client to consume Non-WCF Service and pass Client Certificate

Tags: asp.net, wcf, x509certificate

I have an ASP.NET application that calls a Java Web Service using a WCF Client. The communication works until a certificate is required. I updated the config, but I'm receiving errors on call. Does anyone have good example of the configuration? The certificate is stored in Certificate Store.

Config that works when Client Certificate is not needed:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DocManagementSOAP" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://acme.com/services/docmanagement_V3" 
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="DocManagementSOAP"
                      contract="FileNetDmsServiceReference.docManagement" 
                      name="DocManagementSOAP" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Config that is failing that I'm trying to setup to pass Client Cert:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DocManagementSOAP" 
                         closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                         openTimeout="00:01:00"
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                         allowCookies="false"
                         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                         maxBufferSize="65536" 
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         messageEncoding="Mtom" 
                         textEncoding="utf-8" 
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://acme.com/services/docmanagement_V3"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="DocManagementSOAP"
                      behaviorConfiguration="CertificateBehavior"
                      contract="ServiceReference.docManagement"
                      name="DocManagementSOAP">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="cert.acme.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>     
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CertificateBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="cert.acme.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine"/>
                        <serviceCertificate>
                            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"
                                            revocationMode="NoCheck"
                                            trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
                        </serviceCertificate>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

After working with Microsoft Tech support, this is configuration finally worked:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DocManagementSOAP" 
                         messageEncoding="Mtom" 
                         textEncoding="utf-8">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://acme.com/services/docmanagement_V3"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      behaviorConfiguration="cert"
                      bindingConfiguration="DocManagementSOAP"
                      contract="docManagement"
                      name="DocManagementSOAP" />
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="cert">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate findValue="cert.acme.com"
                                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                           storeName="My"
                                           x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Note: If your service doesn't support MTOM, remove or change the messageEncoding attribute.